# Pass additional parameters through a httpservlet request

Tags: json, servlets, jax-rs

The function `deleteGroup()` deletes a group and one of the parameters for this method is `groupDN`. In the front end I use jquery to specify a HTTP delete request. I was previously sending the `groupDN` by appending it with the URL. I now want to try sending this parameter embedded with the `HttpServletRequest`. The code for both the front and back end is below. Could  someone guide me to the proper way of sending/receiving additional parameters within a request?

**Front end**

```
function removeGroup(groupDN) {

var deleteGroupDetails=new Object();
deleteGroupDetails.groupDN=groupDN;

jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'DELETE',
    url : 'api/groupService/deleteGroup,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(deleteGroupDetails),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    async: false,
    success : function(response) {
        utilDisplayMessage(response,"SUCCESS");
        window.location.reload();
    },
    error : function(obj, error, errormsg) {
        utilDisplayMessage(obj.responseText,"ERROR");
    }
});
}
```

`deleteGroupDetails` contains the `groupDN` parameter which I think I could pass along with the request.

**The back end in Java**

```
@DELETE
@Path("deleteGroup")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String deleteGroup(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

String groupDN = request.getParameter("groupDN");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a request body with a HTTP `DELETE` request. What you try to do is not REST but RPC (Remote Procedure Call) over HTTP. Don't do this.

The HTTP `DELETE` verbs tells the server to delete the resource identified by the URI. So if you do

```
DELETE /path/to/resources/123
```

the resource identified by this URI shall be deleted.

If you want to delete more than one entity on the server with *one* `DELETE` request, craft your resource URI to mean a *collection* of entities. For example:

```
DELETE /path/to/resources/?groupDN=foo
```

could mean: Delete all entities that somehow match the filter `groupDN=foo`.